# Embedding loads of images

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, embed

I got 42 images that I want to embed and then put on an array.
I tried to do it within a for loop, but it doesn't seem to work.
How exactly can I avoid to have 42 embed lines + a very long line for the array ?

Comment: For future reference, the reason the for loop doesn't work is because that loop is run at runtime, whereas embedding occurs at compile-time. These are two distinct run points for an application. You can do conditional compilation, but that really does not help in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to embed multiple images without an embed line for each one is to use a Sprite Sheet (sometimes called a 'Texture Atlas', or simply a 'Sprite').  This will take a folder of images, and generate one large image.  And also give you a data file (use XML or JSON) of all images in your folder and where they're positioned inside the Sprite Sheet.

You can then embed the Sprite Sheet once.

For this you need 2 things:

1/ Software to create your sprite sheet... There are many tools available, the one I use for example is **Texture Packer**: http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker

2/ An actionscript class or framework, designed to handle referencing images from your sprite sheet... This is a native feature of Starling, but if you're not ready to support Flash Player 11 then you can find some publicly available frameworks for this:
For example: **Spriter**: http://abeltoy.com/projects/spriterAS3/usage.html has a class called BitmapSpriter to handle sprite sheets natively in AS3.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a for each loop.

```
var items:Array = ["hi", "there", "bob"];
for (var index in items) {
    trace(index+" => "+items[index]); // traces "0 => hi", "1 => there" and "2 => bob"
}
```